# Finding the distribution function of $F_Y$ in terms of $F_X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have this problem:

> Let X be a random variable with distribution function $F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. And let $Y:=X\mathbb{I}_{(0,\infty)}(X)=\max\{0,X\}$.
> Find the distribution function of $F_Y$ in terms of $F_X$.

And my work is as follows:
$$F_{y}(z)=\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)=\mathbb{P}(\max(0,X) \leq y)=\mathbb{P}(0\leq y)\cup \mathbb{P}(X\leq y)$$

But I don't know how to continue or even if what I've done so far is the right way to do it.
Any clues or suggestion are well-received.

Comment: Well, $y$ is some fixed quantity, so $\mathbb P(0 \leq y)$ , well , it's not an event inside the $\mathbb P$, is it! So from $\mathbb P(\max(0,X) \leq y)$, you'll have to split into the cases $y \leq 0$ and $y>0$. Besides, $0$ is a (constant) random variable so you can use the max logic for multiple independent random variables that is found using a logic of the type $\max\{X_1,...,X_n\} > y$ if and only if $X_i > y$ for all $i$, which are independent events.

Answer (score 1):

You have established that $Y$ shall surely not be less than $0$. Therefore, partition on this case.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y\leq y) &= \mathsf P(X\leq y\cap 0\leq y)\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}0 &:& y<0\\[1ex]\mathsf P(X\leq y)&:&0\leqslant y\end{cases}\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X\leq y)\,\mathbb I_{[0..\infty)}(y)\end{align}$$

So we have $F_Y(y) = F_X(y) \,\mathbb I_{[0..\infty)}(y)$